# RJAGS model will not compile

Tags: r, jags

I'm trying to get my model to compile in RJAGS, but I keep receiving a runtime error that doesn't seem to describe the problem as seen below:

```
model {
  theta ~ dbeta(1,2);
  for (i in 1:N) {
    fp[i] ~ dbeta(1,2);
    fn[i] ~ dbeta(1,2);
    tp[i] <- 1-fn[i];
    tn[i] <- 1-fp[i];
  }
  for (j in 1:M) {
    margprobs[j] <- theta * 
     (fn[1]^(1-x[j,1])) * (tp[1]^x[j,1]) *
     (fn[2]^(1-x[j,2])) * (tp[2]^x[j,2]) 
    + (1-theta) * 
    (tn[1]^(1-x[j,1])) * (fp[1]^x[j,1]) *
    (tn[2]^(1-x[j,2])) * (fp[2]^x[j,2]);

    postprobs[j] <- theta * 
    (fn[1]^(1-x[j,1])) * (tp[1]^x[j,1]) *  
    (fn[2]^(1-x[j,2])) * (tp[2]^x[j,2])
    }

counts ~ dmulti(margprobs, total);
 }
```

Error:

```
Compiling model graph
   Resolving undeclared variables 
Deleting model

Error in jags.model(model.file, data = data, inits = init.values,     n.chains = n.chains,  : 
  RUNTIME ERROR:
Compilation error on line 9.
Unknown function: :

Calls: jags -> jags.model -> .Call
Execution halted
```

My data seems to specify the needed variables:

```
jags.data <- c("M", "N", "x", "counts", "total");
```

Does anyone know what is preventing this model from compiling?

EDIT: This is what the data going in looks like, as print() gives -

```
$M
[1] 4

$N
[1] 2

$x
     Var1 Var2
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    1    0
[3,]    0    1
[4,]    1    1

$counts
[1] 377558   1001   2000   2000

$total
[1] 382559
```

Comment: What do you specify in as data input? Is it possible that something is missing?

Comment: Ah and what does the : at the end of your code 'jags.model(model.file, data = data, inits = init.values,     n.chains = n.chains,  :' mean? Maybe the Compilation error steems from that

Comment: I've added more info on the data, hopefully this helps thanks. The compilation error seems related to the N and M in the model's for statements. If I remove those variables, it will compile.

Comment: In the definition of margprobs[j], where you add the term (1-theta), does the error change at all if you move the addition sign (+) to the end of the previous line, rather than the beginning of that line?